# Obtener datos de un php que se encuentra en una url

Tags: php

Estuve haciendo una prueba de nivel hace unos dias, y me pedian que hiciese una serie de cosas con los select mostrados en la siguiente direccion: http://sitelicon.eu/test/, y para ello tenia que usar la informacion de las localidades y provincias que esataba almacenada en la siguiente url: [http://sitelicon.eu/test/ajax_localidades.php](http://sitelicon.eu/test/ajax_localidades.php%E2%80%A8) , por si solo se hacerlo, lo unnico que no se como sacar la info de una url externa a mi archivo PHP para despues usarlas. Alguien sabe como? muuchas gracias de antemano.

Este es el enunciado que me dieron:

En la siguiente web, realizar un archivo js que sea capaz de mostrar las localidades correspondientes a la provincia elegida en el primer combo. Refrescar el combo de localidades mediante AJAX a medida que cambie el valor del primero.  La url es la siguiente:  http://sitelicon.eu/test/  La dirección que carga las localidades esta otra  http://sitelicon.eu/test/ajax_localidades.php

Esto es lo que tengo ahora copiando de los comentarios:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ejercicio AJAX</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <select id="provincias">
    <option value="1">Álava</option>
    <option value="2">Albacete</option>
    </select>

    <div id="respuesta"> </div>

  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#provincias").on('change', function() {
          var provinciaid =  $(this).val();
             console.log(provinciaid);
          var url = "http://sitelicon.eu/test/ajax_localidades.php?id=" + provinciaid ;
          
          
   
                  $.ajax({
                      type:"GET",
                      async: false,
                      url: url,
                      data: $("#frm_filtrar").serialize(),
                      success: function(data){
                           $("#respuesta").html(data);
                      }
                  });


      }) 
});
  </script>
</html>
```

pero al ejecutarlo en el navegador me salen dos errores, que son estos que os muestro:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://sitelicon.eu/test/ajax_localidades.php?id=1' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

jquery-3.6.0.js:10109 GET http://sitelicon.eu/test/ajax_localidades.php?id=1 net::ERR_FAILED 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Primero tendías que crear un `<select>` con las provincias  y un `<div>` vacío donde mostraremos la respuesta.

```html
//es importante que el value de cada option sea el id de la provincia
<select id="provincias">
  <option value="1">Álava</option>
  <option value="2">Albacete</option>
</select>

<div id="respuesta"> </div>
```

Segundo debes capturar el evento `change` del `<select>` para obtener el `id` de la provincia, enviarlo mediante `ajax` y luego mostrar la respuesta en el `<div>`

> NOTA: asignamos la respuesta directamente en el `<div>` por que es
> html. si la respuesta fuese Json o texto etc. tendríamos que
> implementar mas código

**JQuery**

```html
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#provincias").on('change', function() {
          var provinciaid =  $(this).val();
          //puedes ver el id seleccionado en la consola del navegador 
             console.log(provinciaid);
          var url = "http://sitelicon.eu/test/ajax_localidades.php?id=" + provinciaid ;
          
          
   
                  $.ajax({
                      type:"GET",
                      async: false,
                      url: url,
                      data: $("#frm_filtrar").serialize(),
                      success: function(data){
                           $("#respuesta").html(data);
                      }
                  });
             
             
             
        
      }) 
});
</script>
```

Recuerda incluir la `CDN` de `Jquery`

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Documentacion

[HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)
[AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Comment: he revisado lo que me has mandado y voy a mostrate lo que tengo y el erro que me da, modificando la pregunta

Comment: Esto es por que estas haciendo la solicitud desde un dominio diferente.